# Jetty 7 + MySQL Config [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext]

Tags: java, mysql, jetty, database-connection, c3p0

I've been trying to get a c3p0 db connection pool configured for Jetty, but I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException:

```
2010-03-14 19:32:12.028:WARN::Failed startup of context WebAppContext@fccada@fccada/phpMyAdmin,file:/usr/local/jetty/webapps/phpMyAdmin/,file:/usr/local/jetty/webapps/phpMyAdmin/
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration.configure(JettyWebXmlConfiguration.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:990)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:955)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

I'm new to Jetty and I want to ultimately get phpMyAdmin and WordPress to run on it through Quercus and a JDBC connection. Here are my web.xml and jetty-web.xml files in my WEB-INF directory.

jetty-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="mysql" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/mysql</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
                <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql</Set>
                <Set name="User">user</Set>
                <Set name="Password">pw</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">
<web-app>
    <description>Caucho Technology's PHP Implementation</description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>My DataSource Reference</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/mysql</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet</servlet-class>

        <!--
            Specifies the encoding Quercus should use to read in PHP scripts.
        -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>script-encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <!--
            Tells Quercus to use the following JDBC database and to ignore the
            arguments of mysql_connect().
        -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>database</param-name>
            <param-value>jdbc/mysql</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>ini-file</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/php.ini</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I'm guessing that I'm missing a few jars or something. Currently I have placed the following jars in my WEB-INF/lib directory:

> c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
>   commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
>   commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
>   mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar

I have also tried to put these jars in JETTY-HOME/lib/ext, but to no avail... Someone please tell me what is wrong with my configuration. I'm sick of digging through Jetty's crappy documentation.

Answer (score 22):

Starting with Jetty 7, Jetty has become a project of Eclipse Foundation. During the migration of Jetty 6 to Eclipse Jetty 7, a new package structure has been adopted (see the [Jetty 7 Refactoring](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Getting_Started/Porting_to_Jetty_7/Refactoring) page):

- Classes from `org.mortbay.jetty.webapp` are now in `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp`
- Classes from `org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming` are now in `org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi`

So try with the following `jetty-web.xml` (not tested):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="mysql" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/mysql</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
                <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql</Set>
                <Set name="User">user</Set>
                <Set name="Password">pw</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

But if you don't need fancy things from Jetty 7, my suggestion would be to stick with Jetty 6 (more stable, more documentation, more resources on Internet, less complicated, etc, in other words, less pain).

Comment: Ahh... I smacked myself in the forehead after reading this. Thanks a million mate. I'll give this a whirl right now.

Scott

Answer (score 4):

I got the configuration to work now. I'm posting the corrected jetty-web.xml for Jetty 7.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="mysql" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/mysql</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClass">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
                <Set name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql</Set>
                <Set name="user">user</Set>
                <Set name="password">pw</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

With the following jars in WEB-INF/lib

> c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
>   commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
>   commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
>   mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar

Comment: can you show your code in the class. Do you use "DriverManager.getConnection"?

Answer (score 1):

check to make sure the **OLD** `jetty-env.xml` is not in your classpath - 
In jetty 6 the `jetty-env.xml` begins with this:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
```